# Prove φ is a contradiction or ψ is a tautology if φ ⊨ ψ and φ and ψ have no sentence letters in common.

Tags: logic

Show that if *φ* ⊨ *ψ* but *φ* and *ψ* have no sentence letters in common, then
either *φ* is unsatisfiable or *ψ* is tautologous.

Use the lemma: if $\cal{A}$(Ρ) = $\cal{B}$(P), for every sentence letter P in *φ*, then |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{B}$</sub>.

I see that we can reformulate the question as follows: If *φ* ⊨ *ψ* but *φ* and *ψ* have no sentence letters in common, then
either |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = F or |*ψ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = T in all $\cal{L}$<sub>1</sub>-structures.

I figure the proof will look something like this:

Let's say it's not the case that either |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = F or |*ψ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = T in all $\cal{L}$<sub>1</sub>-structures.

That leaves two possibilities:

(1) |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = T, |*ψ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = T. Can this happen if *φ* and *ψ* have no sentence letters in common?

(2) |*φ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = F, |*ψ*|<sub>$\cal{A}$</sub> = F. Again, I don't know what the implications of *φ* and *ψ* having no sentence letters in common does here.

I am new to proofs, and perhaps I am going completely the wrong direction here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We prove that $\phi$ not unsatisfiable implies that $\psi$ is a tautology, provided that $\phi\models\psi$ and they have disjoint sentence letters.

Assume $\phi$ contains sentence letters $x_1,\dots, x_n$, and $\psi$ contains sentence letters $y_1,\dots,y_m$. 
Assume further that $\phi$ is satisfied in a model $A$, i.e. $|\phi|_A=\top$. 
Let $x_i$ evaluate to $a_i\in\{\bot,\top\}$ in $A$. 
By the given hint, the evaluation of $\phi$ remains the same if we change the model at any other sentence letters (different from all $x_i$'s).

Now take an arbitrary model $B$, and change each value of $x_i$ to $a_i$, yielding a model $B'$. 
Note that we didn't touch $y_j$'s, that is, $|y_j|_{B'}=|y_j|_B$ because they differ from the $x_i$'s.
Consequently, $|\psi|_{B'}=|\psi|_B$.

Finally, in the model $B'$, we have $|\phi|_{B'}=|\phi|_A=\top$, hence $\phi\models\psi$ implies $|\psi|_{B'} =\top$. 
We got $|\psi|_B=|\psi|_{B'}=\top$ for any model $B$, so $\psi$ is a tautology.

Comment: Why does $\psi$ hold at $B'$ by the hypothesis? Have you just arbitrarily chosen that model? And even if you show that it holds in $B'$, how can we then say it holds in $every$ model?

Comment: Please reread my answer. Is it clear how we construct $B'$ by $A$ and $B$? Note that sentence letters  of $\phi$ and $\psi$ are *disjoint* by hypothesis.

Comment: So, $\psi$ and $\phi$ have no element in common. Got it. So we can assume that the elements of $\phi$ (which are not elements of $\psi$) are satisfied by model $A$. Then you've taken another model, $B$, and changed its values to those of $A$, creating $B'$. That $|\phi|_{B'}=|\phi|_A=\top$ follows is clear to me. I don't understand the next step, $|\psi|_B=|\psi|_{B'} =\top$.

Comment: You're almost there. What does $\phi\models\psi$ mean? Apply it to $B'$.

Comment: Thank you. It means that in any model where $\phi$ is true, $\psi$ must also be true. Which means that $\psi$ is true in $B'$. But isn't model $B$ different than model $B'$? After all, we changed the values of $B$ to create $B'$. Why is $|\psi|_{B} =\top$?

Comment: It's the same reason as $|\phi|_A=|\phi|_{B'} $. We didn't touch any variables appearing in $\psi$ when creating $B'$.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because we never established that $|\psi|_{B} =\top$ in the first place. Unless all that is meant to show is that $\psi$ is true in a model that is not $A$, since $\psi$ and $\phi$ do not share elements.

Comment: No. We aim to prove $\psi$ at $B$.

Comment: When we say $\psi$ is a tautology, though, we mean that it is true in $all$ models, correct? That is, $\psi$ must be true in $A$, $B$, $B'$, etc.?

Comment: Yes. But $B$ was taken as arbitrary.

Comment: Apologies for my incompetence here. So $\phi$ ⊨ $\psi$, which means that it $could$ be the case that $\phi = \bot$ and $\psi = \top or \bot$. Why haven't we accounted for that, but instead we have assumed that $\phi = \top$, in which case there must be an $A$ model in which all its sentence letters are true.

Comment: It's not $A$'s sentence letters that are evaluated to true, but it's $\phi$ at $A$. Let me detail my answer..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand this: it is clear that if $|\phi| = \bot$ in all models--ie, if $\phi$ is a contradiction--then $\phi\models\psi$ is trivially true. If this isn't the case, then it must be true that $|\phi| = \top$ in $at$  $least$  $one$ model. We'll call that model $A$. It sounds like what you then go on to say is that for any arbitrary model $B$, despite it containing no sentences found in $A$ (or any model that makes $|\phi| = \top$), there is nothing stopping us from constructing a model $B$ such that $|\psi|_B$ = $\top$. Is this correct?

Comment: $B$ is the arbitrarily given model. We change it on $x_i$'s, that's another model $B'$, but $\psi$ evaluates the same.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier (and it's definitely more symmetrical) to proceed by contradiction. Suppose $\phi$ isn't a contradiction and $\psi$ isn't a tautology. So we have an assignment $A$ (assigning truth values to the sentence letters) that makes $\phi$ true, and we have an assignment $B$  that makes $\psi$ false. Now define a third assignment $C$ giving all the sentence letters in $\phi$ the same truth values that $A$ gave them, and giving all the sentence letters in $\psi$ the same truth values that $B$ gave them.  Such a $C$ exists, because of the assumption that $\phi$ and $\psi$ have no sentence letters in common --- so my definition of $C$ is not trying to give the same sentence letter two possibly different values.   Thanks to the lemma you quoted, $C$ gives $\phi$ the same truth value that $A$ gave $\phi$, namely true, and similarly $C$ gives $\psi$ the same truth value that $B$ gave it, namely false. But these facts about $C$ --- making $\phi$ true and $\psi$ false --- contradict the assumption that $\phi\models\psi$.

Comment: I follow this mostly. If $\phi$ is false under any assignment -- ie, if $\phi$ is a contradiction -- then it is trivially true that $\phi\models\psi$. Under another case, though, $|\phi| = \top$ for at least one assignment, we'll call that $A$. Clearly, then, if it is to remain true that $\phi\models\psi$, then under the assignment $A$ where $|\phi| = \top$, it must be the case that $|\psi|_A = \top$. Here is the step I don't get. Why, then, must we conclude that $|\psi| = \top$ for $any$ assignment -- ie, why must it be true that $\psi$ is a $tautology$ -- and not just be true under $A$?

Comment: To put this another way: where $|\phi| = \top$, it is clear that it $must$ be the case that $\psi$ is true under $some$ assignment -- namely, the assignment under which $\phi$ is true. But how do when then deduce that $|\psi| = \top$ under $all$ assignments?

Comment: Let me repeat: take an arbitrary assignment $B$, and modify it on $\phi$'s letters according to $A$, yielding a new assignment $B'$. *Since $\psi$'s letters are disjoint to $\phi$'s letters*, we have $|\psi|_B=|\psi|_{B'}$. Use $\phi\models\psi$ for assignment $B'$ to obtain $|\psi|_{B'} =\top$.

Comment: Let's see if I can rephrase this: We know that if $\phi = \top$ under an assignment, call it $A$, then, since $\phi\models\psi$, it must be the case that $\psi = \top$. In order to make $\psi = \top$, we cannot use the same assignment $A$ under which $\phi = \top$, since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are disjoint. So instead we take a new assignment $B$, and modify it such that it produces the same evaluations as $A$. Under this modification, model $B'$, $\psi = \top$.

Comment: I hope I got that right. Now, my question remains: you have clearly demonstrated that we $can$ produce a model -- namely $B'$ -- under which $\psi = \top$. But I'm meant to prove that $\psi$ $must$ be a tautology. That is, that we couldn't possibly produce a model $C$ under which $\psi = \bot$. I still don't quite see how we have proven that.

Comment: @vundabar You seem to be commenting on a version of the proof closer to Berci's answer than to mine. Perhaps you should read one of the proofs slowly and carefully and **not** try to guess what we (Berci or I) **should** be doing --- instead, think about what we actually wrote.

Comment: We are *first* given an **arbitrary** model $B$. *Then* we modify it to make $\phi$ true but not touching $\psi$ (we can do it because of the *disjointness hypothesis*). *Using the other hypothesis*, $\phi\models\psi$, we have $\psi$ is true in $B'$. Since at modification we didn't touch $\psi$'s letters, $\psi$ **must have been true** in the original arbitrary model $B$.

Comment: @Berci It makes a lot more sense thinking about it this way! So if $\phi$ and $\psi$ do not share sentence letters, then necessarily they are evaluated under different models. And if we start with any model where $\psi$ is true (we know it must be true under at least one model if $\phi$ is satisfiable) and modify that model to make sure $\phi$ is true, we will never tamper with the fact that $\psi$ was true under the original model.

Comment: Well, a model assigns a truth value to *all sentence letters*, including all $x_i$'s and all $y_j$'s. Now the point is that $\phi$ only cares the $x_i$'s and $\psi$ only cares the $y_j$'s. In that circumstance $\phi\models\psi$ is a quite strong criterium, that's what this exercise is about.